# What are the E7(7) invariants in the adjoint representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, invariant-theory

Take a real vector space $R$ transforming in the adjoint representation of
the ${\rm E}_7(7)$ Lie group as $R \rightarrow G R G^{-1}$. One can define
invariants using traces of products of $R$ as ${\rm Tr}[R^k]$.

I heard that a basis of invariants is given by $k = 2,6,8,10,12,14,18$.
Is this correct? Which theorem states this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The question is out of focus, starting with "the $E_7(7)$ Lie group".  It's not clear what this means, but the invariant theory of the associated Weyl group does lead to a polynomial ring of invariants (Chevalley) geneerated by algebraically independent homogeneous polynomials of degrees $d$ which you've listed with the index $k$.   This in turn provides a picture of invariants in the simple  complex Lie algebra of type $E_7$ via Harish-Chandra's isomorphism.   All of this is found in standard textbooks, so I think the question is not currently at research-level.

Comment: $E_{7(7)}$ refers to the split real form, not the complex $E_7$.

Comment: Among "standard textbooks" let me recommend Jim Humphreys' "Reflection groups and Coxeter groups".